# How to feed response of one function to another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have a class like this:

```
class MyModule {
  constructor() {
    this.val = 0;
  }

  foo(a,b) {
    this.val = a+b;
    return this.val
  } 

  bar() {
    return this.val + 10
  }

  silly() {
    return __isGreaterThan(50)
  }
}
```

Now I want to be able to use the above class in the following different way as shown below as `res1` and `res2`.

```
const xyz = require('myModule');

const res1 = xyc.foo(5,10).bar().silly();
const res2 = xyz.foo(5,10);

console.log(res1) // Outputs --> false
console.log(res2) // Outputs --> 15
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: you'll need to return `this` in `foo` and `bar` - you'll also need to instatiate that class - as it is you're using classes **all wrong**

Comment: you can't return two things. You either need to return the object or a number.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I forgot to create the instance. Is there a way that in res2 I can directly get the value without using .val? I’m trying to simulate numpy’s np.arange(15).reshape(3,5) from Python in nodejs. And if I just do np.arange(15) I should just get the output instead of doing .value or .list or something

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with minimal changes of your code outputting what you want

Note: in your code, you don't ever create an instance of MyClass, I think you need to learn how class works

```js
class MyModule {
  constructor() {
    this.val = 0;
  }

  foo(a,b) {
    this.val = a+b;
    return this;
  } 

  bar() {
    this.val += 10;
    return this;
  }

  silly() {
    return this.val > 50;
  }
}
// in a separate file, you'd do something like
//
// const MyModule = require('myModule');
//
// obviously, won't work in this snippet, but that's the only difference 
// with what your real world code would need

const xyc = new MyModule();
const xyz = new MyModule();
const res1 = xyc.foo(5,10).bar().silly();
const res2 = xyz.foo(5,10).val; // note: you need to get the `val` property

console.log(res1) // Outputs --> false
console.log(res2) // Outputs --> 15
```